# Make value=null when page first loads

Tags: php, jquery, osclass

Is it possible to remove a value whilst the page is loading?

I'm using [OSClass](http://osclass.org/), and on one of the pages it's by default adding a value for region (cambridshire):

[image]

I need to clear this value since it's causing problems, everytime I type something else in, by default, it registers it as Cambridgeshire...

If I look at code for it:
[image]

It's being generated by a function (can see my JQuery attempt to clear it which hasn't worked).

Then if I search the function is splits up in many different parts, so I don't know where to go from there.

Basically, is there a way to remove the value when page loads and save the new value when the user submits?

[JSFiddle](http://bit.ly/Z88r09) - Note it won't display anything due to the way code is generated

Comment: That jQuery script looks OK and it could be another reason that it does not work. If you open your browser console, do you see any errors? I'm assuming jQuery plugin is included.

Comment: @Spokey No error and yes JQuery works fine on other parts of the website but it's failing to override the php code...However, I think Clive, (below), may have solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried removing `<?php ItemForm::region_text(); ?>` on it's own? Or passing an empty string `<?php ItemForm::region_text(''); ?>`

I'm not familiar with OSClass though I'm afraid.

Comment: I've tried removing the <php> function all together but then it won't generate an input box, I will try passing an empty string and get back to you

Comment: sorry, that's why i suggest passing nothing or an empty string

Comment: Your solution appears to be working :D! I need to make sure it's not screwing anything up behind the database so let me test and I'll accept your answer if it flows :)

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code below the `jQuery` initialization:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#region").val('');
})
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, is this correct? The value going into databse is still "cambridgeshire" http://i.imgur.com/MqLhknx.png